# Can visualVM be integrated inside netbeans

Tags: netbeans, visualvm

Can visualVM be integrated inside netbeans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not exactly the same, VisualVM's core is based on the same core as the Netbeans profiler so you it's pretty likely that what you are actually looking for is the profiler that is integrated into Netbeans.